# std::forward and ref-qualifiers for member functions

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14, perfect-forwarding

I was in a position where I was using `std::forward` wherever I had a forwarding reference and I was wondering if some of that was unnecessary or even wrong.  For example having `std::forward` in a `std::begin()` call.

Because of the ability of a class being able to overload its member functions based on whether the call is made with the object as an rvalue or not https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2014/06/02/ref-qualifiers/,  I assumed that a templated function would be as efficient as possible if you were knew that the inner function you were forwarding the object to was non-mutating and/or was a member function of the object.  For example

```
template <typename Something>
void do_something(Something&& something) {
    std::forward<Something>(something).do_something();
    auto iter = std::begin(std::forward<Something>(something));
    for_each(iter, std::end(std::forward<Something>(something), []() {});
}
```

I saw this question ([When not to use std::forward with r-values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12048889/when-not-to-use-stdforward-with-r-values)) but it did not address the member function ref-qualifiers and it also did not clearly address what the best practice is when you don't have access to the inner functions definitions that you are calling.

Is there a general guideline for when not to use `std::forward` that addresses the things I mentioned?  Or is there some key concept that I am missing?

Comment: `std::begin()/end()` isn't a great example here - the "rvalue" versions would just yield const iterators, there's no ref-qualification going on.

Comment: @Barry Doing that was what got me to this question.  I just wanted to make the background of this clear so that people understand where I was coming from.

Comment: If you use a rvalue version, you must accept the fact that the called function may yank your object and leave a valid-but-nulllike state afterwards

Comment: @krzaq What about the case when you know your function is non mutating and/or is a member function?

Comment: @Curious Well, if you know that and still have a use case for using different code for lvalues/rvalues, I'd say go for it.

Comment: @krzaq it just feels wrong to me for some reason.  Like something in me is screaming "this is not the intended use of `std::forward`" and I just wanted the opinion of some people who knew more about this than I do :)

Comment: @Curious Well then, there is a reason why I commented instead of outright answering ;)

Answer (score 1):

Except if you know the type you will have, avoid to use `std::forward` several time in the same function for the same object, as the second time, your object might be moved.

```
// assuming implementation which really need pass by value instead of const reference
template <typename T> void pass_by_value(T t) { std::cout << t; }

template <typename T>
void foo(T&& t)
{
    pass_by_value(std::forward<T>(t));
    pass_by_value(std::forward<T>(t));
}
```

a call of `foo` with `std::string`

```
foo(std::string("Hello world")); // or "Hello world"s
```

might call the equivalent to

```
    pass_by_value(std::string("Hello world"));
    pass_by_value(std::string("")); // Moved string...
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a use after object moved from ("stealed"). If `something` used in a multiple lines of `do_something`, then use `std::forward` only at the last such line to prevent the problem.